# "Пришел с братом и с другом" или "Пришел с братом и другом"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Пришел с братом и с другом" или "Пришел с братом и другом"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это как Вам хочется. Предлог, стоящий перед первым однородным членом, может опускаться перед остальными однородными членами, но может и повторяться перед каждым из них. Ср.: Хозяин, из почтения и радости, ничего не ел… (Пушкин). – Феничка вся покраснела от смущения и от радости (Тургенев Я бы для благозвучия предлог опустила. Подробнее здесь:    http://hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-168.htm

Comment: спасибо,а как насчет местоимений,с ними тоже так же? "Пришел с ней и ним. Здесь чувствую, что нельзя,но не знаю везде ли так.

Comment: Фразу напишите, я что-то не соображу, о чём идёт речь

Comment: спасибо,а как насчет местоимений,с ними тоже так же? "Пришел с ней и ним. Здесь чувствую, что нельзя,но не знаю везде ли так

Comment: Нет, здесь нельзя, неблагозвучно получается.Надо: Пришёл с ней и с ним.А лучше:Пришёл с НИМИ.

Comment: Так нормально. Знаки препинания: "А так:пришел с ним и сестрой?"

Comment: (а так, пришел с ним и сестрой ?) (а так? пришел с ним и сестрой.) И в каком предложении знаки препинания правильно расставлены?

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!!! А ЕСЛИ НАОБОРОТ

Comment: После "так"двоеточие, потому что дальше следует разъяснение, что именно так.Кавычки я поставила, потому что цитирую Вас, скобки в таких случаях не ставят.